# If the additive group of $H^*(X;R)$ has no elements of order $2$, prove that if $\beta \in H^*(X;R)$ has odd degree, then $\beta \cup \beta =0$.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

> If the additive group of $H^*(X;R)$ has no elements of order $2$, prove that if $\beta \in H^*(X;R)$ has odd degree, then $\beta \cup \beta =0$.

I can see that since $\cup$ is a cup product, I would have to show (assuming $\beta = \text{cls } \phi$) that  $\text{cls } \phi \cup \text{cls } \phi = \text{cls } (\phi \cup \phi)=0$.

Since no elements are of order $2$ and $\beta$ is of odd order, we have $2 \space \text{cls } \phi = \text{cls } \phi + \text{cls } \phi \neq 0$ and $(2k+1) \space \text{cls } \phi = 0$.

But I'm not sure how I would connect these two concepts.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: $a\cup b=(-1)^{|a||b|}b\cup a$

Comment: @ReneSchipperus What is that theorem called?

Comment: Look at lemma 12.22.

Comment: @Tyrone Any particular book ?

Comment: Rotman's algebraic topology book, which I believe Oliver is studying from (the question appears in it as *12.17.)

Comment: I realized now that I misread "degree" as "order".  And Theorem $12.29$ about anticommutativity the name of the theorem assuming $a$ and $b$ are cohomology classes.  But if $\beta=b$ has odd degree, then $b \cup b = -b \cup b$, and therefore $b \cup b + b \cup b = 0$.  And since no element has order $2$, $b \cup b = 0$.